# How to do versioning to clear browser cache in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I have minified and bundled all the '.js' files and also attached a version number using gulp task. When I'm trying to load the app it is showing the following error.

"Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=UserProvider%20%3C-%20User%20%3C-%20HomeController ".

Any help, could be appreciated.

Comment: does it work in development version? Also will get more verbose error and stack trace output using non minified angular development version.

Comment: It works well in development since I don't minify the code in development version.

Comment: Are you using inline annotation to avoid issues when minimizing?

Comment: I guess you might be using implicit dependency injection. Try include ng-annotate or babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate in your gulp workflow. https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate